# global variables(Communication between components in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, reactjs-flux

Is it good idea to use global variables for communication between 2 components in react.js.
Or is it bad practice.

If no, can somebody explains, whats are the drawbacks of it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your use case? Ideally components should not communicate with each other aside from a parent passing its child props.

Comment: child-child communication.. and passing certain authentication values from one child to another.. is it going to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any global variables in most cases is bad practice in React applications.

If you have some data, which should be used by many components, consider using some Flux library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: can you please explain me why its bad practise?

Comment: @komaldeepsinghchahal, when you are using global variables, it become very hard to understand what value these variables have, and where they come from. Handling your data in a single place makes understanding of your app more easier.

Answer (score 1):

One of the core value propositions of React is one way data flow. Among other benefits, it makes it easy for developers to reason about as they trace the data flow. You don't want child-child communication, instead I would suggest structuring your app such that the parent can pass data to both children.